# ASP.NET Core HttpContext.User always empty

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have weird behavior using asp.net core 3.1 which is as follows When I called

[image]
This is called in AccountController.Login action method
The result return with Succeeded, and user will redirected to Dashboard/Index action method, however when I check HttpContext.User.Identity
[image]

It always return with empty identity object that have default values for all its inner properties.

I tried to set the value manually but it still the empty object even when I set it to null

Here is full ConfigureService method that I use
[image]

Comment: ASP.NET Core version?

Comment: I have guessed the problem. Could you please add  full code of the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class?

Comment: Be sure that you call the middleware in the order like below: `UseRouting`, `UseAuthentication`, `UseAuthorization`, and `UseEndpoints`.

Comment: Thank you Rena that was the problem I was forgot to add 'UseAuthentication' which was made that weird behavior, please add it as an answer to check it right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to be sure that call the middleware in the order like below: `UseRouting`, `UseAuthentication`, `UseAuthorization`, and `UseEndpoints`.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#configure-identity-services

Comment: Could you please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77647669/httpcontext-user-not-populated-in-net-core-app