# HttpContext.User not populated in .NET Core app

Tags: asp.net-core, httpcontext, asp.net-core-identity

I wonder why the `User.GetUserId();` returns 0 wherever it's used. What's the problem?

Actually, the `IsAuthenticated = false` for the `User` object.

I tried to test my application using Postman and Angular client applications. In both ways, the token is returned to the client successfully. In Postman I add the received token to the authorization field of the header like this:

```
Bearer <the token>
```

After sending the request to another action that contains `User.GetUserId();` I get the same result. and `User.GetUserId();` is still 0.

`Configure` method in `Startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();
  
    app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowCredentials()
            .WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200"));

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Fallback");
    });

}
```

`Login` method in `AccountController`:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto>> Login(LoginDto loginDto)
{
    var user = await _userManager.Users
                                 .Include(p => p.Photos)
                                 .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == loginDto.Username.ToLower());

    if (user == null) 
        return Unauthorized("Invalid username");

    var result = await _signInManager
                           .CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, loginDto.Password, false);
 
    if (!result.Succeeded) 
        return Unauthorized();

    var token = await _tokenService.CreateToken(user);

    var userDto = new UserDto
        {
            Username = user.UserName,
            Token = token,
            KnownAs = user.KnownAs,
            Gender = user.Gender
        };

    var uId = User.GetUserId(); // it returns 0

    return userDto;
}
```

`TokenService.cs`:

```
public class TokenService : ITokenService
{
    private readonly SymmetricSecurityKey _key;
    private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;

    public TokenService(IConfiguration config, UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["TokenKey"]));
    }

    public async Task<string> CreateToken(AppUser user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
                         {
                             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId, user.Id.ToString()),
                             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, user.UserName.ToString())
                         };

        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        claims.AddRange(roles.Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));

        var creds = new SigningCredentials(_key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),
                SigningCredentials = creds
            };

       **//UPDATE**
       var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
       _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);


        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

after updating `CreateTokenAsync()` as you can see in the code I got the proper result from `User` in the login controller after calling `CreateTokenAsync()`. but after that when I called another endpoint the `HttpContext.User` became empty!
Having said that I injected `IHttpContextAccessor` into the class that `CreateTokenAsync()` is located.

Comment: I’d suggest you to use the built-in authentication services to handle your authentication, and use ASP.NET Core Identity if you want a login functionality with your own user accounts. If you roll your own login mechanism, you will need to hook into the authentication stack if you want e.g. `User` to work. Because `User` will just look at the claims identity that is provided by the authentication middleware but the way you set it up, no claims identity is set up.

Comment: Try specific the scheme :[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] Identity would modify your default authentication shceme

Comment: @poke thanks for your response. I used `ClaimsPrincipal`. it helped a little but there is still a problem. I updated the question